# Cannot cast from object to long

Tags: java

I'm not so good at java and I'm  trying to figure out how to fix this issue.
This is my code :

```java
            final Method method1 = method;
            final Object o = object;
            LongSupplier longsupplier = new LongSupplier()
            {
                private boolean disabled = false;
                public long getAsLong()
                {
                    if (this.disabled)
                    {
                        return -1L;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                        return (long) method1.invoke(o); 
                        }
                        catch (Throwable throwable)
                        {
                            Config.warn("" + throwable.getClass().getName() + ": " + throwable.getMessage());
                            this.disabled = true;
                            return -1L;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            return longsupplier;
```

The issue is that in the `return (long) method1.invoke(o);` it say this error : `Cannot cast from Object to long`.

Comment: well, likely method.invoke(0); returns something that can't be cast to long. What exactly does it return?

Comment: @Stultuske no, that is a compiler error.

Comment: ehm ... yes, so how was my statement incorrect?

Comment: @Stultuske Aw, rats. You were trying some socratic method stuff. I misunderstood your comment and now gave it away in an answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not so good at java (this isn't my code, but I'm using it in my project) but it seems to return a string.

Comment: I‘m not quite sure what you‘re trying to do, but you can‘t convert from Object to long, because long is a java primitive, which doesn’t extend Object. They therefore don‘t share a base class. This means that you can‘t use Polymorphism to Cast. int, char, long, float, boolean, all those are primitives. All other types inherit the Object class. I‘d suggest you read up on Java primitives and the Object tree.

Answer (score 1):

The code feels indicative of bad java code (java isn't dynamic, don't try to treat it as some sort of javascript or python. There are solutions to this such as SPI, factories, etc). However, if you insist on continuing with it: You'd cast to `Long`, not `long`. Then you can just return that (the compiler will figure it out and auto-unbox it), or if you want to do *that* by hand too, call `.longValue()` on that.

Comment: I'm trying to use `long` and not `Long`. `long` is a variable.

Comment: `long` cannot be a variable, given that it's a reserved keyword. Just do what I say, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a typed and not an untyped language for example javascript, although the name may be similar. Therefore, it should only be used in this way. Method is not a valid type, so no type conversion to (long) can be implemented. Therefore there are two "simple" possibilities either you build a new class, which can/is also a new type or you get the result of a method. Unless Method is a class you create, this won't work.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57471_01/bigData.100/extensions_bdd/src/cext_transform_typing.html